# AngularJS - "10 $digest() iterations reached" when ng-view ng-repeat dependant on $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I am really new to Angular and this is the first time that I am dealing with routing, so please excuse me if my questions are a bit confusing. My actual logic and structure for this app is much more complex and I am using several services, but this is the general idea of the part that I am having issues with. I would really APPRECIATE your help! Thanks.

### SOLVED

### I was adding the same template recursively. Inside the template, I changed that ng-repeat template to another one and it worked perfectly.  http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgiAngelov/9yN3Z/111/

UPDATED
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeorgiAngelov/9yN3Z/106/

**I updated my fiddle thanks to Chandermani ( I removed all the controllers and left only one copy of it) but now I get "10 $digest() iterations reached" whenever I click on the Add Root button OR whenver I click on a section it keeps giving me that error... No idea why.**

So I have an app where I have a menu on my left side where I can add more elements called **sections** to that menu. That menu **section** item is derived from an array called **sections** that sits in my controller and when you add a **section** it adds it to the array named **sections**.

```
$scope.sectionId = $routeParams.sectionId;
$scope.sections = [];
$scope.counter = 1;
$scope.section = {};

$scope.addSection = function(){
    $scope.sections.push({
        id: $scope.counter++,
        name: 'Random Name',
        roots: []
    });   
};
```

**HTML for sections **

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left pull-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-click="setSectionSelected(section)" ng-class="{active : isSectionSelected(section)}"><a href="#/section/{{section.id}}" data-toggle="tab">{{section.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="addSection btn btn-success" ng-click="addSection()" style="position:relative; bottom: 0;">Add Section</button>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active : isSectionSelected(section)}" id="{{section.id}}" ng-repeat="section in sections">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Every object in that array has another array called **roots** and with another button, named **Add Root**, I want to push objects(elements) to whatever section I am currently on, depending on the $routeParams id variable.

```
$scope.addRoot = function(section){
    section.roots.push({
        id: $scope.counter++,
        name: 'Random Root',
    });   
};
```

**HTML template that is called from the router**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    <div class="map-container">
        <div class="map">
            <h2>{{section.name}}</h2>
            <h4>{{section.description}}</h4>
            <button class="add btn btn-success" ng-click="addRoot(section)">Add Root</button>
            <div ng-repeat="root in section.roots" ng-include="'/tpl.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/section', {
        templateUrl: '/tpl.html',
        sectionId: '1',
      })
      .when('/section/:sectionId', {
        templateUrl: '/tpl.html',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Where do you get undefined

Comment: @Chandermani, I just added it to the top of my thread. I get the error when I click on the addRoot button.

Comment: There are multiple issues with you code. For base html, ng-include and ng-view you are using the same controller. Remember that all three cases new controller would get created. Also in the html you do not use `$scope.section.roots` but `section.roots`

Comment: @Chandermani I changed a few things around right before you commented. Yeah I totally overlooked some things but it is still not working. I will try removing copies of the controller.

Comment: Now it is working but I am getting errors with repeating the same template over and over. Some kind of loop that I can't figure out why.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I already solved it above. Thanks for commenting though.